# Update Firebase ChildByAutoID

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update - that means adding new fields inside the childByAutoID created in the database: see below

[image: Database Structure]

How should I write the code in order

How can I write an update function for this?

Comment: I want to enter the database and update the values inside, adding new options, not only the 3 you see

Comment: You need to either get that node, or know it in order to update it. For example, suppose the user's node you want to update contains the email *alex@alex.com*. You would *query* for that node first, obtain the key, and then write out additional child key: value pairs to that key. If you are storing users by their UID, then you could simply write additional child key: value pairs that that known UID. The question is; how do determine which node you want to write the data to? Is it something a user selects or is it the currently logged in user? Something else?

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `updateChildValues` method, as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

and therefore do something like:

```
let key = "-LDHt9B......."
let post = ["newData1": ....,
            "newData2": .....]
let childUpdates = ["/isWorker/\(key)": post]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Comment: Actually I think the OP might be facing difficulty to get to the `autoID` field as well.

Comment: @nayem Well, IMHO, I think that if you want to update an existing object it somehow means that you know its ID. So I make the assumption the OP already knows the object's ID, either because he has its value somewhere in the app (in a cache or similar) or he finds it through a query.

Comment: It didn't work... I am trying to check what should I do in order to update... maybe I need to change the childByAutoID and add something else that can be more easily changed?

Comment: Can you update your post with the exact **detailed** flow: how do you create the data the first time, when and how do you want to update it, how do you identify the data you want to update (do you have the Id, i.e. "-LDHt9B......."?), etc. And as much of your code as possible.